# How can I insert into a table both a select max function from another table and variables input by the user, using PHP, SQL and Microsoft Access?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I want to insert a record into the Booking_Sheet table when the user enters their information on an HTML document. First, some of the information is stored in the Client_Database table, and then I want the rest of the information to be stored in the Booking_Sheet but I want the record on the Booking_Sheet to contain information that was just inserted, such as the AutoNumber Client_ID from Client_Database, which I am doing with a select max statement. Although this is not working. I was wondering if it is possible to have a SELECT statement imbedded within VALUES?

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Booking_Sheet (Client_ID, Client_Name) 
    VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Client_Database), '$name');";
    if(odbc_exec($con,$sql))
    {
        echo "<br>Data saved<br>Please Wait Page redirect..";
        header("refresh:1;url=index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Learn to use parameters!

Comment: This is also a question involving the software you use to generate the html and call SQL (is it PHP?)  In fact ot may be more important than the SQL. tag you question with this too.

Comment: Really should not save client name into Booking_Sheet. That is duplicating data between tables. Just save Client_ID. Are you confident Max will return ID of this client? Are there multiple simultaneous users of this db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not. I just tried within Access and it fails. However, don't need VALUES.

`"INSERT INTO Booking_Sheet (Client_ID, Client_Name) SELECT MAX(ID), '$name' FROM Client_Database";`